# AngularnVMWare clarity vcenter search component - is the source anywhere?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am interested in replicating the search component that is used in VMWare Vcenter with clarity (type ahead show results in a centralized search box in nav).  The docs show examples of implementing the box itself, but not the typeahead component.  Before I started rolling my own I was interested to see if there was one preexisting.

Comment: There is a new component that will be in v4. You can check it out in the rc that is on npm: npm i @clr/angular@next. The docs aren’t published just yet. Hopefully next week. But if you are comfortable poking around the code base look in apps/website/components for early bird info.

Comment: FYI - It’s called Combobox.

Comment: All source code for Clarity can be found in their repo, which they link to multiple times: https://github.com/vmware/clarity